# Kubernetes Pods failed hours ago, how to debug a terminated pod

Tags: kubernetes, logging

I have a deployment of pods which failed 22h ago, how often does Kubernetes log-rotate its logs?

Is there any possibility to view the logs of the deployment but 22 hours ago?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can not retrieve logs from a pod that is not in ready state.
We can get the logs of the container inside the pod , By logging into the worker node where pod was running .

- `docker ps -a | grep <pod name>`
- `docker logs <container name/id from above output`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **kubectl logs --previous** to retrieve logs from a previous instantiation of a container.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kubernetes **does** **NOT** provide built-in log rotation.
2. Check official [Debug Running Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/) documentation:

> If your container has previously crashed, you can access the previous
> container's crash log with:

```
kubectl logs --previous ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}
```

3. In my opinion you are asking not about logs on pod, you are more interested in full debug. Your starting point is again official documentation  [Troubleshoot Applications-Debugging Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/#debugging-pods). ANd start check with `kubectl describe pods ${POD_NAME}`

4.All I wrote above is great, however sometimes the only way to get the logs is @confused genius answer.